# Filters products by manufacturers, Brands, Price etc in android

Tags: magento-1.7, filter, soap-api-v2

Hi I am developing magento e-commerce application in android. I want to filter products with Manufacturers, Brands, Price etc.
Is this possible using magento's "catalogProductList" ksoap2 api?

Below is my code which is working for single filter "price".

```
SoapObject filterResult = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "catalogProductList");
                filterResult.addProperty("sessionId",sessionID);

                SoapObject value = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "associativeEntity");
                value.addProperty("key", "in");
                value.addProperty("value", "50.0000");

                SoapObject complexFilter = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "complexFilter");
                complexFilter.addProperty("key","price");
                complexFilter.addProperty("value",value);

                SoapObject filterArray = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "complexFilterArray");
                filterArray.addProperty("item",complexFilter);

                SoapObject filters=new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "filters");
                filters.addProperty("complex_filter", filterArray);
                filterResult.addProperty("filters", filters);
```

for the above code how can I send array of filters ?
Ex : Price (100 to 200),(300 to 400)
     Brands (Brand1,Brand2,Brand3 etc)?